# windows event 4647 occurs randomly - windows server 19

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2019

we are facing an issue windows server 2019 event 4647 occurs randomly which shuts down a window service app we have written that use that account.

at random times, a 4647 windows event is generated that causes our custom windows service to stop working which relies on the user to be logged on. the logoff is not done manually by any human but this event randomly shows up.

any help appreciated to either stop the event from occurring or re-login the user automatically (using any powershell or batch script) so that the windows service doesn't stop.

tried to set auto logon and other group policies with no avail.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This event is defined as "Event 4647(S): **User initiated** logoff." Please add to your post all the information included with this event. The XML data of the event is best.

Comment: @harrymc thanks for the reply. let me try to ask the server team if they can provide any log. actually the issue is that due to this, the windows service stop working and needs to be manually started again after logging in the user.

Comment: What service are we talking about exactly? [Edit] your question instead of replying with a temporary comment. Commentary is temporary and is subject to be flagged and removed. Clarification of your question should be done as an edit.

Comment: @Ramhound updated question description. its a custom written windows service.

Comment: The optimal solution should involve the service being rewritten to run without a user logged in. That's how services are supposed to run, and Windows Server isn't intended to have users logged in long term.